# QUnit ignore global failures

Tags: qunit, chutzpah

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14481029/how-to-stop-global-failures-in-qunit) post is from more than a year old, again this question. Is it already possible to ignore the global failures in qunit?

I am using Chutzpah in my project, so I am not going to make edits in qunit's source code as one of the answers suggests.

It is because the js code that is to be tested uses external dependencies, but I do not want to test them Can I exclude the global failures?

Comment: Are the global failures causing your test run to fail?

Comment: The global failure is displayed as a test that failes. All other tests pass but I don't want the global failure to be displayed.